# How to automate jprofiler & integrate with jenkins?

Tags: python, shell, ant, jenkins, jprofiler

I want to automate Jprofiler and also integrate whole process with jenkins. I have searched google  a lot but not able 
to find proper way to do so. Till now I have two options,
1. Use ant task, but there isn't much more in documentation. Like if I want to profile particular package or some set of class or only CPU etc. So this doesn't seem best option.
2. Automate **jpcontroller.sh** via shell or python script, but I'm not great in shell or python.

So my question, how can I automate and integrate jprofiler with jenkins???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Use ant task, but there isn't much more in documentation. Like if I want to profile particular package or some set of class or only CPU
>      etc.

The profiling settings are not configured in the ant task, but in the JProfiler GUI. In the ant task you use the `configfile` and `sessionid` attributes to refer to the configured session. The session ID is displayed in the top-right corner of the "Application settings" tab in the session settings dialog.

Automation is done with triggers. Each trigger has a list of actions. For more information on how to set up triggers for offline profiling see the [corresponding help topic](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/config/triggers.html).